# Unable to install package from pip

Tags: python, pip

I have tried to install Requests like this:

```
python3 -m install requests
```

but it's not working.

[image: Have a link at this link]

Comment: Try it : python3 -m pip install requests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using pip incorrectly. You should run `pip` command from the command line, not in Python:

```
C:\Windows\system32> python3 -m pip install requests
C:\Windows\system32> python3
Python 3.6.1........
>>> import requests
```

Read [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-packages) carefully.

Comment: Yes, but you invoked `pip` as a Python command, not in your shell... Run `pip` **before** you run `python`.

Comment: When i did that i got an error that fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '""

Comment: @AkshayArora You are welcome! If you think that this solved your problem, accept the answer and enjoy coding with Python ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if it is in python, it will give a syntax error. Try it right when you open up the cmd.

In this link, I am in python:

[image]

But in the command prompt, it works:

[image]

Well, as for me, I have it already installed in Spyder.